# How can I access href that is inside a data-field, using selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium for web scraping, and I have the following HTML:

```html
<a data-field="---" class="---" target="---" href="https://www.example.com/0000/">
        <div class="display-flex align-items-center">
            <span class="mr1 hoverable-link-text t-bold">
```

How can I access the href link and click on it?
I used the following and didn't get results, would be great to understand why:

browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "https://www.example.com")

browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'https://www.example.com')]")

Thanks!

Edit:
The page I'm working on is the LinkedIn interests page (companies that I follow). You can find it on: https://www.linkedin.com/in/yourusername/details/interests/?detailScreenTabIndex=1

For each company I follow, there is an HTML:

```html
<a data-field="active_tab_companies_interests" class="optional-action-target-wrapper 
          display-flex flex-column full-width" target="_self" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/1016/">
        <div class="display-flex align-items-center">
            <span class="mr1 hoverable-link-text t-bold">
              <span aria-hidden="true"><!---->GE Healthcare<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->GE Healthcare<!----></span>
            </span>
<!----><!----><!---->        </div>
<!---->          <span class="t-14 t-normal t-black--light">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><!---->1,851,945 followers<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->1,851,945 followers<!----></span>
          </span>
<!---->      </a>
```

I want to find href, in my example: "https://www.linkedin.com/company/1016/"

The code I wrote (with the help of the comments):

```
# log in
browser.get("https://www.linkedin.com")
username = browser.find_element(By.ID,"session_key")
username.send_keys("youremail")
password = browser.find_element(By.ID,"session_password")
password.send_keys("yourpassword")
login_button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sign-in-form__submit-button")
login_button.click()


# companies I follow on Linkedin
browser.get("https://www.linkedin.com/in/username/details/interests/?detailScreenTabIndex=1")
# find all company links
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
company_page = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@href,'https://www.linkedin.com/company/')]")


for x in range (len(company_page)):
    print(company_page[x].text)
```

The output for "GE healthcare" (from the HTML snippet) is:
GE Healthcare
GE Healthcare
1,852,718 followers
1,852,718 followers

and not the href link that I'm looking for. I don't understand why it finds these texts and not the link.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://www.example.com/0000/` is not a text attribute content. It is a value of `href` attribute. This is why both you locators are wrong.
Please try this:

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@href,'https://www.example.com')]")
```

Adding a `.click()` will probably click on that element, as following:

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@href,'https://www.example.com')]").click()
```

You may probably will need to add a delay to wait for the element to be clickable. In this case `WebDriverWait` expected conditions is the right way to do it, as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'https://www.example.com')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It didn't find the href link, but found text under the same anchor:
 <span class="mr1 hoverable-link-text t-bold">
              some text<span aria-hidden="true"><!----><!----></span><span

Comment: But in the question you presented `href` attribute with value. also, I'm not sure this element can be clicked with Selenium directly since it is hidden. `span aria-hidden="true"`

Comment: Can you share all your code including the link to the page you are working on?

Comment: What element is it?

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of print(company_page[x].text), I wrote:
print(company_page[x].get_attribute("href"))